# Is there a way to get handle after doing a ssh to linux server in python

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm new to programming and my requirement is to run multiple commands (not sequentally) on two linux machines from my automation server. I have gone through the documentation of `Paramiko` and trying to use this module for doing ssh to two linux machines.
I was able to do the ssh successfully but looks like the `SSHClinet` does not return any value. so i had to repeatedly execute the login codes to login to both the machines and forth. Instead of executing the login code everytime, is there a way to have the handle of the two machines which i can call at will?

The Login code that i have written is:

```
    def loginMachines(self, ip, username , password, role, retries = 1):
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    for x in range(retries):
        try:
            ssh.connect(ip, username = username , password = password)
            banner(self.log, 'SSH to {0} machine is successful'.format(role))
            return True   >> if this can return a handle i can use the same method to login to both linux machines and manipulate with the handle?
        except (paramiko.BadHostKeyException, paramiko.AuthenticationException, paramiko.SSHException, socket.error) as e:
            self.log.info(banner('Exception : {0}'.format(e)))
            return False
```

Comment: What *two* machines? Your code logs in to *one* machine one.

Comment: I login to server and run a script which will  login to two linux machines to start the server and client respectively and start the traffic between them. i can run two script one to run on server and the other on client but just thinking if i start my script from a single server which will internally login to two linux machines..

Comment: I just posted the code to login to one machine. only IP will change for the second machine. but since I have to execute different commands on client and server sequently i thought having a handle of client and server machine would help. to some extent i can achieve this by invoking a shell but not sure if thats the right way.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578) – Please ask about your actual problem, rather than about your imagined way to solve it.

Comment: I was able to get the ssh handle just by returning the ssh . I was able to resolve the issue. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just returning the ssh solves the problem.

```
    def checkSSH(self, ip, username , password, role, retries = 1):
    ssh = SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    for x in range(retries):
        try:
            ssh.connect(ip, username = username , password = password)
            banner(self.log, 'SSH to {0} machine is successful'.format(role))
            return ssh
        except (paramiko.BadHostKeyException, paramiko.AuthenticationException, paramiko.SSHException, socket.error) as e:
            self.log.info(banner('Exception : {0}'.format(e)))
            return False
```